# make docker-compose block until healthy without `depends_on`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working with a team that uses docker-compose to start a set of helper services, but does not use docker when the code is being developed.

Here, docker-compose is just a convenient way to run the helper services while we develop the main server code.

We have a lot of custom code that tries to detect if the helper services are healthy. I would like to use the `healthcheck` feature of docker-compose.

However, docker-compose does not block unless you define some service as `depends_on: ...  condition: service healthy`. In my case I've done this stupid thing; I've simply run hello-world and made it block on the other services being healthy.

```
  helper1:
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://helper1:1234/ready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  helper2:
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://helper2:5678/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  hello-world:
    image: docker.io/library/hello-world
    depends_on:
      helper1:
        condition: service_healthy
      helper2:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Having a dummy service seems inelegant. Is there another way to make my `docker-compose` command block until everything is healthy?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Compose file format 3.x, it only waits for the service to start, not become healthy. It starts the services in the order specified by the depends_on field, but it doesn't wait for a service to be healthy before moving on to the next service.

If you still want to make sure a service is healthy before proceeding, you could use script. The Script will check the health status of your Docker service:

```
#!/bin/bash

service=$1

until [ "$(docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health.Status}}' $service)" == "\"healthy\"" ]; do
  echo "Waiting for $service to become healthy"
  sleep 1
done
```

Save above script as wait_for_health.sh or how you want it to be called.
To use this script just call `./wait_for_health.sh your-container-name`.
You can add `docker compose up -d` command into the script, sothat you dont have to call the docker compose command extra.

Comment: This is useful to the extent that we can locate the definition of "health" with the Dockerfile or in the docker-compose file... but in the end I'm going to need custom code to run before my main service starts, there's not a ton of advantage over just pinging the health endpoints myself

Comment: @NeilK Sorry, but there is no other solution other than building own script because Docker has not functionality to do, what you want to do.